# How to synchronously scroll tab layout with recycler view Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I am trying to achieve scroll tab layout change when recycler view is changed as well as change recycler view when scroll tab layout is changed.

Here is my code:

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
 
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        isScrolling = false;
        llm.scrollToPositionWithOffset(tab.getPosition(), 0);
        RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(mContext) {
            @Override
            protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
                return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
            }
        };
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(tab.getPosition());
        llm.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
});
 
 
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
            isScrolling = true;
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
 
        if (isScrolling) {
            int position = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if (position != tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()) {
                TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
                tab.select();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Below is the animation what I want to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8rZ2.gif

If you know how to fix, please share it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this https://www.programmersought.com/article/19583740487/